# How to make header of RecyclerView stick to top when zooming

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a header of my RecyclerView(as an itemDecoration) that sticks to the top while scrolling normally, but my custom RecyclerView also zooms, but when zooming in the header zooms off the screen. How do I zoom the header with the RecyclerView, but keep it stuck to the top of the screen?

Header:

```
public class RecyclerViewHeaderDecorator extends ZoomRecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private static final String TAG = RecyclerViewDecorator.class.getSimpleName();
private View header;
private int layoutResId;

public RecyclerViewHeaderDecorator(int layoutResId) {
    this.layoutResId = layoutResId;
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    header = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layoutResId, parent, false);
    if (parent.getChildCount() > 0) {

        // Specs for parent (RecyclerView)
        int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        // Specs for children (headers)
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec, parent.getPaddingLeft() + parent.getPaddingRight(), header.getLayoutParams().width);
        int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec, parent.getPaddingTop() + parent.getPaddingBottom(), header.getLayoutParams().height);

        header.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

        header.layout(0, 0, header.getMeasuredWidth(), header.getMeasuredHeight());

        canvas.save();
        header.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
}
```

RecyclerView:

```
public class ZoomRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
private static final String TAG = ZoomRecyclerView.class.getSimpleName();

private float scaleFactor = 1.f;
private static final float minScale = 1.0f;
private static final float maxScale = 3.0f;

public ZoomRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            //makes sure user does not zoom in or out past a certain amount
            scaleFactor = Math.max(minScale, Math.min(scaleFactor, maxScale));

            //refresh the view and compute the size of the view in the screen
            invalidate();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
        //notify the scaleGestureDetector that an event has happened
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    //scales the display, centered on where the user is touching the display
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleGestureDetector.getFocusX(), scaleGestureDetector.getFocusY());

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
}
```